# Passing ifstream not recognized

Tags: c++, ifstream

I'm getting this error message

> error: no matching function for call to
>   HCTree::build(std::basic_ifstream < char, std::char_trait< char>> &)
>   const
>
> note: candidates are: HCNode* HCTree::build(std::ifstream&) < near
>   match>

in .cpp

```
int HCTree::decode(ifstream &in) const {
    if(root == NULL) {
        root = build(in); <-- error here
    }
    return aux_decode(in, root); <-- similarly error here too
}
```

in .hpp

```
HCNode* build(ifstream &in);
```

I don't quit understand what am I doing wrong

Comment: Have you included `<fstream>` from the header?

Comment: Yep, do have it included.

Comment: You are trying to call a non-const member function from a const one. It doesn't normally work

Comment: `const` overload? Signature in hpp has no `const`.

Comment: it says it is looking for build(ifstream&) const and it is finding a non const version.  You can't call a non const version from inside a function that is const because if build modifies the object then decode was lying.  Can you make build const?

Comment: @n.m. can you elaborate please?

Comment: @Jack Since `decode` modifies the object, it shouldn't be `const`.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a constness problem.

Just a wild guess, but does your HCTree class inherit from HCNode?

You're trying to call a non-const member function from a const function, which is illegal. Furthermore, assuming root is a non-mutable member variable of the HCTree or HCNode class, trying to modify it in the const decode function is also illegal. Try removing the const qualifier from HCTree::decode, since it seems not to be const at all.

Alternatively, if root is not a non-mutable member variable, you could declare HCNode::build as const, assuming it actually doesn't mutate any state.